# Переводы с Binance-python

Tags: python, blockchain, binance

Всем привет, такой вопрос:
Есть ли метод у Binance api для осуществления транзакции со своего счета на счет другого пользователя (На любой кошелек)?
Допустим со своего спотового кошелька отправить TRX на кошелек bybit(Допустим)
Api и Secret имеется. Буду очень благодарен если укажите на данный метод

Comment: Кошелек в той же сети? Или вообще где-то за мостом?

Comment: @MadJackal Где то за мостом

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, может кому пригодится

```
 client = Client(api_key=api_key, api_secret=api_secret)
 try:
     # name parameter will be set to the asset value by the client if not passed
     result = client.withdraw(
        coin='BTC',
        address='Адрес куда будете выводить',
         amount=15.000)
 except BinanceAPIException as e:
     print(e)
 else:
     print("Success")
```